# Unknown column 'photos.gallery_id' after doing db:reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After I pulled a rake db:migrate:reset, some code stop working. When trying to view my galleries index page I get: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'photos.gallery_id' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `photos`  WHERE `photos`.`gallery_id` = 1

If I remove one line of coding from index.html it will work: <%= gallery.photos.size %>

I have not modified any code. This all happen once I did the reset. Curious as how to fix it.

index.html:

```
<% for gallery in @galleries %>
    <div class="gallery">
        <h2><%= link_to gallery.name, gallery %></h2>
        Photos: <%= gallery.photos.size %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<p><%= link_to "New Gallery", new_gallery_path %></p>
```

The proper column is "gallery_id" so I am not sure why it is trying to pull "photos.gallery_id".

Comment: Does your gallery table have a photo_id column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error says, there's no column 'gallery_id' in your 'photos' table. You could try to inspect the database and check if this exists. You could try:

```
rails c
> Photo
```

And see if there's a field called 'gallery_id'.

You should try running `rake db:migrate`.